# Write a function that prints the first word after the first space in a string

Tags: python

Programming Challenge 5: Write a Python function called secondword.  The function should take a single input that will be a string.  If there is no space character in the string, the function should output an empty string (a string with no characters between the quotes).  If there is a single space character in the string, the function should output a string containing the slice of the input string that is after that space.  If there are two or more space characters in the string, the output should be the slice of the input string after the first space up to but not including the second space.

For example:

```
secondword("United")
should return ''
second word("United States")
should return 'States'
secondword("United States of America")
should return 'States'
```

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service.  You must write this yourself, then come to us if it does not work.

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easily done with re - good luck with the challenge

```
import re
def secondword(s):
    p = r' ([^ ]*)'
    m = re.search(p, s)
    return m[1] if m else ''
```